How to add total column to end of table?
I'm relatively new to python and inherited a code from a colleague that I can't seem to get to run. The idea is to get a Totals row and column added to the dataframe, however the line for the column does not work and gives multiple errors (I see a lot of "Traceback (most recent call last)"):
csmposting = create_csm_table(csm)
csmposting['TOTAL'] = csmposting.sum(axis=1)
csmposting.loc['TOTAL'] = csmposting.sum(axis=0).astype(int)

When I run it without the second line I get (I've removed the column headers):
Unit1   779 285 16  2   3
Unit2   290 20  3   3   0
Unit3   0   0   3   7   0
Unit4   547 97  8   10  0
TOTAL   1616    402 30  22  3

I've tried changing that line to:
csmposting.loc['TOTAL1'] = csmposting.sum(axis=1) 
This only ends up adding it as another row at the bottom of the table and adds a decimal place to all the numbers:
Unit1   779.0   285.0   16.0    2.0 3.0
Unit2   290.0   20.0    3.0 3.0 0.0
Unit3   0.0 0.0 3.0 7.0 0.0
Unit4   547.0   97.0    8.0 10.0    0.0
TOTAL1  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
TOTAL   1616.0  402.0   30.0    22.0    3.0

Can anyone advise on how to get the totals column to show and keep the number format the same?
Thank you!

The full error I get when running the code is:
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897             try:
-> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'TOTAL'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3575         try:
-> 3576             loc = self._info_axis.get_loc(key)
   3577         except KeyError:

/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2895                 )
-> 2896             casted_key = self._maybe_cast_indexer(key)
   2897             try:

/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/category.py in _maybe_cast_indexer(self, key)
    436     def _maybe_cast_indexer(self, key):
--> 437         code = self.categories.get_loc(key)
    438         code = self.codes.dtype.type(code)

/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2899             except KeyError as err:
-> 2900                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2901 

KeyError: 'TOTAL'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-abfa7a59ea03> in <module>
      7 
      8 csmposting.loc['TOTAL'] = csmposting.sum(axis=0).astype(int)
----> 9 csmposting['TOTAL'] = csmposting.sum(axis=1)   # Convert row totals to integer
     10 
     11 csmposting

/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3042         else:
   3043             # set column
-> 3044             self._set_item(key, value)
   3045 
   3046     def _setitem_slice(self, key: slice, value):

/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3119         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
   3120         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
-> 3121         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   3122 
   3123         # check if we are modifying a copy

/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3577         except KeyError:
   3578             # This item wasn't present, just insert at end
-> 3579             self._mgr.insert(len(self._info_axis), key, value)
   3580             return
   3581 

/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in insert(self, loc, item, value, allow_duplicates)
   1190 
   1191         # insert to the axis; this could possibly raise a TypeError
-> 1192         new_axis = self.items.insert(loc, item)
   1193 
   1194         if value.ndim == self.ndim - 1 and not is_extension_array_dtype(value.dtype):

/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/category.py in insert(self, loc, item)
    738         if (code == -1) and not (is_scalar(item) and isna(item)):
    739             raise TypeError(
--> 740                 "cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex "
    741                 "that is not already an existing category"
    742             )

TypeError: cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not already an existing category


I edited my reply below. My suspicion is you just have an old version of pandas and you need to upgrade. I was able to reproduce your error in pandas v1.2.5 but not in more recent versions.

Here is the sample code using Pandas that reproduces
the two TOTAL calculations and seems to work fine
even when the columns index is CategoricalIndex.
import pandas as pd

col_index = pd.CategoricalIndex(['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5'])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[779, 285, 16, 2, 3],
     [290, 20, 3, 3, 0],
     [0, 0, 3, 7, 0],
     [547, 97, 8, 10, 0]],
    index=['Unit1', 'Unit2', 'Unit3', 'Unit4'],
    columns=col_index
)

print(df)  # similar to your sample data in `csmposting`
#         c1   c2  c3  c4  c5
# Unit1  779  285  16   2   3
# Unit2  290   20   3   3   0
# Unit3    0    0   3   7   0
# Unit4  547   97   8  10   0

df['TOTAL'] = df.sum(axis=1)         # TCOL

df.loc['TOTAL'] = df.sum(axis=0)

print(df)
#          c1   c2  c3  c4  c5  TOTAL
# Unit1   779  285  16   2   3   2170
# Unit2   290   20   3   3   0    632
# Unit3     0    0   3   7   0     20
# Unit4   547   97   8  10   0   1324
# TOTAL  3232  804  60  44   6   8292

The code on line marked # TCOL auto-convert the data frame's index to Index and I don't get an error, when using pandas==2.2.2.
My suspicion is the pandas version in your code environment is very old and the problem will go away if you upgrade it. You can use the command pip freeze to see which versions of the packages are in your environment, and pip install -U pandas to upgrade to the latest version.
If upgrading pandas is not an option, here are is a related thread with info about modifying a categorical index:
TypeError: cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not already an existing category

Hi Ivan, thanks for the response! I can confirm the two commands are in separate lines (I've edited the post). I've also included the error I keep getting when running the code. Do you have any ideas on what is happening?
